# Product revenue cube (using SSAS) too big and slow browsing

Tags: sql-server, ssas, hierarchy, product

Got a question regarding big size SSAS cube:

Scenario: .. building product revenue cube on SQL Server Analysis Server (SSAS) 2012: 
the product hierarchy is a dimension with 7 levels: cat1, cat2, … cat7(product_id);
The fact table is at product id level, key = (customer id + bill month + product id), this gives around 200M rows per month, may still go up.

Concern: Now the prototype is having only 3 month data, the cube browsing are slow already. When drag and drop 2 -3 dimensions, it might take couple of minutes or more.
Late on, there are 30+ other dimensions need to add in, and extend to 1-2 years data, 2-3B rows. So we are concerning the performance, can that much data be handled with an acceptable browsing speed?

Question: Is there any better way (design, performance tuning) for above scenario?

E.g. another thinking is to make the fact table flat, i.e. make it customer level, key = (customer id + bill month), one customer only have one row per bill month. While adding 40+ columns, one column for each product, that way the fact row count per month with go down to say 5M. But we can’t build/browse the product dimension anymore (that is an important requirement), can we?

Thanks in advance for any light shedding.

Comment: What exactly is it that you won't be able to do if you use a flat table, and why is it important.   I would advocate the flat table approach, so far, but will wait to know more about the case against it.

Comment: Product hierarchy is a regular dimension with 7 levels, we like to pivot it at any level. e.g. 5 product_ids (level 7) belong to product category 6-a (level 6), when we use flat table, we would not be able to join the production dimension at product_id level to roll up, since now we have 40 product_ids in one row. Instead we can define calculated measures, like Rev-6a = Rev-7-1 +Rev-7-2 + ... Rev-7-5. but to define calculations for all members in all levels will be too many, and most disadvantage is we can not pivot it in the way of a dimension.